# How to add Vuex 3 for Vue 2,7?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

When I run: yarn create nuxt-app 
I see in package.json that I have:

```
"dependencies": {
   "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
   "vue": "^2.7.10",
},
```

I need to use Vuex.
For this environment, I must use Vuex 3.
So I do what the [documentation](https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#direct-download-cdn) says: `yarn add vuex`. But this always leads to the installation of vuex 4:

```
"dependencies": {
   "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
   "vue": "^2.7.10",
   "vuex": "^4.1.0"
},
```

But this leads to various issues because [vuex 4](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#direct-download-cdn) is suitable for Vue 3 only.

The result of running `yarn add vuex` is the same as running `yarn add vuex@next --save`.

How to install vuex 3 for Vue 2.7  in my Nuxt project ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn add package-name` installs the “latest” version of the package.
`yarn add package-name@1.2.3` installs a specific version of a package from the registry.

Try `yarn add vuex@3`